# Accessing instance of a component in Vue (CKEditor)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to use a method in the CKEditor instance, [on( 'paste', function( evt ))](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-on).

[In the Vue CKEditor doc](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_vue.html#editor-instance) it says:

> if you need access to the editor object, you can use the editor property of the component’s instance:
>
> component.instance.getData();

I cant understand how that maps to my current template, because:

1. `console.log(this.$refs.editor)` is defined
2. `console.log(this.$refs.editor.instance)` is undefined
3. `console.log(this.$refs.editor.on())` is not a function

My vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <ckeditor ref="editor" :editor-url="editorUrl" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vue component of CKEditor uses these provided events https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html#component-events. If you like like to use other events which are not provided by the CKEditor vue component, you can build the CKeditor from source https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html#ckeditor-5-built-from-source. In this way, you can configure the CKeditor instance in Vue's component's `mounted()` property.

```
   import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor";

   mounted: function() {
        ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector("#editor"), editorConfig).then(
          editor => {
            this.editor = editor;
            this.editor.model.document.on("change", () => {
              this.updateContent(this.editor.getData());
            });
          }
        );
      },
```